# Java Keytool jdk/jre 64/32bit - Is there a difference?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, keytool, jarsigner

I noticed, there are Java 4 different Keytool.exe(and jarsigner.exe) on my computer.
For either Java 64bit or 32bit and either in the jdk and jre directory.

Does it make any difference, which one I use to sign my jars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the functionality is the same. It's just included in the jre and the jdk, and if you happen to have several of them, you'll have several keytool.exes.